# Svelte dev server is stuck on old version

Tags: svelte, rollupjs

I'm using Svelte with Rollup. I've always had a great dev server experience using npm run dev. Now, though the dev server seems stuck on an older version of my application. If I deploy with run build I get my latest changes, but npm run dev attempts to run the same thing from yesterday every time. I think this may be a browser session/cookie issue, as localhost:5000 in a chrome incognito tab served the latest version... but now it is also stuck on that version and won't update as I make and save changes. Any tips?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably need to disable the cache.

Open Dev Tools -> Network Tab -> Disable cache (top checkbox).

Comment: thanks Carlos. I had the same issue while following the Svelte tutorials., your answer fixed it.

Comment: I wish svelte had something to invalidate local cache, but this works, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Nothing on internet worked for me in this case, so I found following to (sort of) unblock myself

```
npm run build
npm run preview
```

This allows me to check the progress of my work.

Disadvantages of going this way:

- Your changes are no longer live, you need to run these commands again in order to load any new changes.
- It no longer retains the actual file structure. It has built your project for production, so it does some optimisations. As a result of which, it will be hard for you to debug the code in browsers.